# Where can I find list of magento blocks?

Tags: magento-1.8, blocks

I'm new to magento and struggling to find the purpose of various blocks. I tried to google but could not find a single page where atleast definition is given.

So, please someone give me a link where I can find the list of all magento blocks and their purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such list but you can check the blocks by enabling path hit, To enable path hit follow the steps :

**System > Configuration > Developer > Debug**.

- Profiler : yes
- Template Path Hints : yes
- Add Block Names to Hints : yes

[image]

Now all the blocks with path displayed at front end.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

there's no such link, all blocks are inside Block folders and their purpose is defined by methods they implement